# discord.js - How to get specific collected message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to get specific collected message, e.g. third collected message. The forEach works perfect, but I need just one specific, like I said previously.

```
collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} messages`)

    message.channel.send(`${collected}`)

    collected.forEach(value => {
      message.channel.send(`${value}`)
    })
})
```

Comment: This is maybe a bit naive but.. does `collected[2]` work?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it will send "[object Map]"

Comment: As per your comment as as per documentation, the type of the parameter "collected" is and array of key value pairs. So "value" is a key value pair/map. You can follow this documentation to see how to iterate a map - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collected` is a `Collection`, not an array. You can find the [documentation here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection).

You could use the [`.at(index)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=at) method that returns the item at a given index. So in order to get the third item, you could use the following:

```js
let thirdCollectedMessage = collected.at(2)
```